# nodejs download image with superangent ,check the file size

Tags: node.js, download, fs, superagent

```
...
superagent
            .get(req.body.img)
            .set('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36')
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
console.log(fs.statSync(filePath));
...
```

The output is
    {"dev":2049,"mode":33204,"nlink":1,"uid":1000,"gid":1000,"rdev":0,"blksize":4096,"ino":6578368,"size":0,"blocks":0,"atime":"2016-07-18T02:46:12.845Z","mtime":"2016-07-18T02:46:12.845Z","ctime":"2016-07-18T02:46:12.845Z","birthtime":"2016-07-18T02:46:12.845Z"}

why the file size is 0, i have check the file size with :

```
console.log(fs.statSync(filePath));
```

{ dev: 2049,
  mode: 33204,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 1000,
  gid: 1000,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 1975657,
  size: 1964074,
  blocks: 3840,
  atime: 2016-07-18T02:29:16.977Z,
  mtime: 2016-07-18T02:28:30.037Z,
  ctime: 2016-07-18T02:28:30.037Z,
  birthtime: 2016-07-18T02:28:30.037Z }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, you call `console.log` while stream write to file. Try add listener on `finish`.

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
stream.on('finish', function () {
    console.log(fs.statSync(filePath)); 
});

superagent 
    ...
    .pipe(stream);
```

Comment: This is due to async createWriteStream method :)